# tikz-timing & T1 fontenc

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, tikz-timing

When using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, the text output produced by `tikz-timing` is rastered; the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                

\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}
& 2D{a} \\
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

results in this output:

[image]

This is independent of the document class, and only happens if I specify `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Even with just `\usepackage{fontenc}`, the output is ok. Unfortunately, I have no idea on how to even approach debugging this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the cm-super fonts. Or add `\usepackage{lmodern}`.